# Special canonical labelling functions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-isomorphism

Given a graph class $\mathcal{G}$, a function $\mathcal{f}$ defined on $\mathcal{G}$ is said to compute canonical forms of $\mathcal{G}$ if it satisfies the following:

$$\forall G,H \in \mathcal{G} :  if G\cong H \equiv f(G) = f(H)$$
$$\forall G\in \mathcal{G}:   f(G) \cong G$$

Now there are some function for which this problem is hard and easy for some others. What are the examples of $f$, for which above problem is easy to solve.

Comment: This is a little hard to parse. Do you mean that for all $G,H\in \mathcal{G}$, if $G$ and $H$ are graph isomorphic if and only if $f(G) = f(H)$, and moreover for all $G\in \mathcal{G}$, $f(G)$ and $G$ are isomorphic? And are you asking for (nontrivial) examples of such canonical labelling functions $f$?

Comment: @ Alex  yes exactly